# Doubt with a proof in Convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-explanation

Theorem : If $c \in (0,1) $, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} c^{n}=0$.

Proof : If $ 0 < c < 1 $, we claim that  $0 < c^{n + 1} < c^{n} < 1 $. This can be easily shown by using Induction. Thus we have that $\{c^{n}\}$ is a monotonic decreasing sequence and bounded below. Thus $\{c^{n}\}$ is convergent.

let  $L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} c^{n}$. We need to show that $L = 0$. Let
$\epsilon > 0.$ Then $\exists N\ \in ℕ $
such that $ \forall n ≥ N$, we have :
$ \\ \: |c^{n} - L| < (1 - c)\dfrac{\epsilon}{2} $. (I got this part).

*Therefore,

$\ |1 - c||L| = |Lc - L| = |L - c^{N + 1} + c^{N + 1} - cL| ≤ |L - c^{N + 1}| + c|c^{M} - L| < (1 - c)\dfrac{\epsilon}{2} + c(1 - c)\dfrac{\epsilon}{2} < (1 - c)\epsilon $
Thus,  $\forall 
 \epsilon > 0, |L|< \epsilon \implies L = 0.$ $\blacksquare$

*I want to ask that how did we get this? Is it simply by manipulating.i.e,

$|c^{n} - L| < |c - L| < |Lc - L|$
But then how did he came up with this? I know that if $|1 - c||L| < |1 - c|\epsilon$ then also, $|c^{n} - L| < |1 - c|\epsilon$ but we already chose a epsilon for $|c^{n} - L|$, so I really do not get this part. Can somebody intuitively explain this to me like how does this proof actually works? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numbering each step:
$$\begin{align*}
  |1 - c||L| 
&\stackrel{(1)} = |Lc - L| \\
&\stackrel{(2)} = |L - c^{N + 1} + c^{N + 1} - cL|  \\
&\stackrel{(3)} ≤ |L - c^{N + 1}| + c|c^{N} - L|  \\
&\stackrel{(4)} < (1 - c)\dfrac{\epsilon}{2} + c(1 - c)\dfrac{\epsilon}{2} \\ 
&\stackrel{(5)} < (1 - c)\epsilon   
\end{align*}$$

- $(1)$ follows just by bringing the absolute values together: $|ab|=|a||b|$
- $(2)$ follows because $c^{N+1}-c^{N+1}=0$. We add this and subtract this inside to get two expressions we can deal with based on previous work, expressions of the type $|L-c^k|$.
- $(3)$ follows by the triangle inequality. We don't apply it to every term, though; again, the goal is just to get terms we have already bounded. In the latter term, we will also factor out a common factor of $c$.
- $(4)$ follows by the definition of $N$. Note that, loosely speaking, since $c^{N+1} \le c^N$ (after all, it's a decreasing sequence), we know that $c^{N+1}$ is closer to $L$ than $c^N$, and hence can apply its bound to both of the absolute values. (I leave it to you to formalize and prove this.)
- $(5)$ is just a matter of combining like terms.

Comment: Thank you for that, um can also explain that how did you get that |1 - c||L| from where?

Comment: The goal is to show $|L| < \epsilon$; is equivalent to show that $|1-c| |L| < (1-c) \epsilon$, and that is more convenient for our purposes considering the bounds on $|L-c^n|$

Answer (score 3):

Another maybe easier way is to use the fact that every subsequence of convergent sequence converges to the same limit. Note that if $L=\lim c^n$ then $$L^2=\lim(c^n)^2=\lim c^{2n}=L$$
Where the last step is true since $c^{2n}$ is a subsequence of $c^n$. As $L<1$, it must be the case that $L=0$.